# Erasing an object from a vector found by iterator causes segmentation fault

Tags: c++, vector, segmentation-fault

I have a class called `Object` that is defined like this:

```
#include "Object.hpp"

Object::Object()
{
    id = 0;
}

int Object::Id()
{
    return id;
}

void Object::setId(int i)
{
    id = i;
}
```

I have a container class that holds a bunch of these `Object`'s called `DataSet`. I am currently holding them in a `std::vector`. In the `DataSet` header file, I have these functions I want to do and I also have a `std::vector` of `Object`'s:

```
class DataSet{
public:
    std::vector<Object*> objects;
    DataSet();
    ~DataSet();
    int addObject(Object *object);
    void clear();
    int deleteObject(Object *object);
    int getSize();
};
```

Since my `Object` right now is basically just associated with an ID, I wanted to be able to use find and delete the `Object` that has a specific ID. However, when calling `objects.erase`, I end up getting a segfault. Here is my method:

```
int DataSet::deleteObject(Object* object)
{
    std::vector<Object*>::iterator iterator;
    if(object) {
        iterator = find(objects.begin(), objects.end(), object);
        delete *iterator;
        objects.erase(iterator);    // seg fault
    }
    return 1;
}
```

In my `driver`, here is how I'm removing something by ID:

```
void execRemove(int id)
{
    DataSet dm;
    Object *temp = new Object();
    temp->setId(id);
    dm.deleteObject(temp);
}
```

Why is calling `erase` on the iterator causing a seg fault? Also in my `deleteObject` my only requirements are that I use an `iterator` and `find` since I'm measuring the time it takes to remove an `Object` from a `std::vector` of millions.

Edit: As a side note this `DataSet` is getting initialized by doing this:

```
for(int i = 0; i < 1000000; ++i) {
    Object* object = new Object();
    object->setId(i);
    dm.addObject(object);    // dm is our dataset container
}
```

Calling `execRemove(20)` ends up seg faulting, even though `dm` for sure has the `id: 20`.

Comment: How do you know `find()` isn't returning the `vector::end()` iterator? Passing that to `vector::erase()` is undefined behavior.

Comment: The deleteObject probably isn't finding anything because the object you're looking for (the temp) was never actually added. Perhaps instead of finding the object by comparing pointers, you actually want to look for object(s) with the same Id and delete them instead?

Comment: @qeadz I do want to do that, but it specifically says I have to implement `find`. Would I still be able to accomplish this?

Comment: @Alex if you specifically need to use find and you're wanting to find an entry given a key (in this instance it's an Id) then use a map instead of a vector.

Comment: @qeadz I know this sounds dumb I also have to use a vector :(

Comment: @Alex well two options come to mind: use std::find_if with a predicate that compares the Id's of the objects, or have a vector<Object> (no pointer) and overload the operator== for Object to compare Id's.

Comment: @qeadz Thanks! I did std::find_if and it seems to work fine now :)